# python's round() function not working?

Tags: python

below is my program for finding approximate root for a some 5000th-degree polynomial that is given as a series:

```
def s(r, z):
    sm = 0
    for k in range(1, z+1):
        sm += (900-3*k) * r ** (k-1)
    return sm

target = -600000000000

n = 1
dr = .125
curr = 0
while abs(curr - target) > 1:
    curr = s(n, 5000)
    if curr > target : n+= dr
    else : n-=dr
    dr /= 2
```

I wanted it rounded to 12 digits behind decimal point, hence

```
print round(n, 12)
```

which gave me :

```
1.00232210863
```

number is approximate enough, but it is now rounded to 12 digits. I fired up python console and found it myself :

```
>>> n
1.0023221086328755
>>> round(n, 12)
1.002322108633
```

Why is my round() function working only inside python console prompt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By deafault python's print rounds numbers to 11 digits when printing.
Try instead

```
print '%0.12f'%n
```

To be a little more clear, when you are in the interactive console and do:

```
>>> x = 1.123456789012345
>>> x
1.123456789012345
>>> print x
1.12345678901
```

Remember that the the first call is actually a call to

```
x.__repr__()
```

which will print as much information about x as it can, while the print statement translates to

```
print x.__str__()
```

and the builting **str**() method on ints rounds to 11 digits if necessary. You can force as many digits as you like using python's % formatting as shown above.